# fetch date using Regex in R

Tags: r, regex, date, datetime

I have the various file name as given below:
    file<-"/path/path/path/pth.0p25.2015011500.p264.path2.pathpathh254004.nc"

**Problem 1**:
I want datetime part(2015011500)from the above file. I have written the below code:

```
# Fetching the date vlaue from the filename
a<-substr(gsub("[A-z]|[////]","",file),6,13)
 a
[1] "20150115"
hrs<-substr(gsub("[A-z]|[////]","",file),14,15)
hrs
[1] "00"
#concatenating both date and a as one
chr<-paste(a,hrs, sep=" ")
chr
[1] "20150115 00"
```

But when I am trying to convert chr to date. I am getting NULL value.

```
#Converting chr variable to date
datetime<-as.Date(a,format="%Y%m%d %H")

Result:
datetime
[1] NA
```

**Problem 2**:
I want to fetch 264 from the file name. Code for this is given below:

```
validhrs<-substr(gsub("[A-z]|[////]","",ncfname),17,19)
Result:
validhrs
[1] "264"
```

I want to convert this validhr to time(hour).And then add this to datetime

Anyone could help me with this?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: you use `a` instead of `chr` in the `as.Date` function. If you use `chr` the `as.Date.` or `as.POSIXct` will work properly.

Comment: For your frist problem, use `as.POSIXct` (which is for date-times) instead of `as.Date` (which is only for dates).  Dates don't include hours and minutes.

Comment: FYI: [`[A-z]` matches more than just letters](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29771926/3832970).

Comment: @D.sen and @NathanWerth, I used as.POSIXct and I am getting the following value:`datetime<-as.POSIXct(chr,format="%Y%m%d %H%M%S")
> datetime
[1] NA`. Any Comments?

Comment: ^ Do not add the `%M%S`, your string does not reflect that format

Comment: `datetime <- as.POSIXct(chr,format="%Y%m%d %H")`

Comment: @D.Sen , thanks it worked. I am getting below output: `datetime
[1] "2015-01-15 EST"`. Here, I am not getting time component. Is it because  hour is 00 in my case?

Comment: Correct, switch `hrs` to `1` for testing purposes. You'll see the hour value.

Comment: Thanks @D.sen. Could you help me with 2nd problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154268/discussion-between-d-sen-and-kaushik).

Answer (score 1):

**Answer to Question 1:** How to extract date from string, then convert it to date class:

```
x <- "/path/path/path/pth.0p25.2015011501.p264.path2.pathpathh254004.nc"

#Extract the date:
x <- gsub(".*(\\d{10}).*",'\\1',x)

#Convert to POSIXct:
x <- as.POSIXct(x,format="%Y%m%d %H")
```

Output:

```
[1] "2015-01-15 01:00:00 PST"
```

**Answer to Question 2:** How to add number of hours, "...p264..." in this case, to x:

```
hrs <- gsub(".*[p]+(\\d{3}).*","\\1",x)

require(lubridate)

x + hours(hrs)
```

Output:

```
[1] "2015-01-26 01:00:00 PST"
```

Note: 264 hours (i.e. 11 days) were added to what was once "2015-01-15 01:00:00".

Comment: then how to convert it to datetime? Any comments on problem2?

Comment: Thanks. Could you help me in solving problem2?

Comment: @Kaushik - Solved both; see above.

Comment: @Kaushik - If this was helpful, please remember to mark this answer as the solution to help the community know it's solved and to help others with similar questions to find their answer even faster.